# Promise in Node.js for storing and using a JSON inside the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, promise, node-fetch

I have a code that takes the JSON of a webpage (from a link) and prints it into the console with a promise, using *node-fetch* (npm node-fetch) and *.then*

I need to get the content of this specific webpage to work with that content for a project I have, but I cannot see any solution on how to really use it

I have this code:

```
fetch('https://api.faceit.com/core/v1/nicknames/'+req.query.nickname)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(body => console.log("json -> "+body))
```

req.query.nickname is a text variable taken from a form that will serve for the link I use to print the JSON

now, when I get to *.then(body => console.log("json -> "+body))* it correctly prints me the JSON but I have no clue on how to use the body that I print

Now, after all this, I have 2 questions

- how can I used the "body" variable to work with the data I get out of that link?
- is there any different way (better or not) to get the content from a page, stored into a variable or an Object, that I can work with?

thanks for everyone for the help in advance. If you need an example of the JSON I need to work with, you can use this https://api.faceit.com/core/v1/nicknames/noxter

Comment: Yes and now, it does make it more clear than what to do and what no, but in the solutions part it just prints the thing it needs to print
I need to use it, not to print it. This is my issue, still thanks for sharing that thread, made many things clear

Comment: Then just replace the `console.log` with whatever it is you need to actually do? It's only in there that you have access to `body`. Note I'm not suggesting that you write your entire program inside the `.then` callback - but it would be normal to write a function which takes `body` as the argument, then just call it from the `.then`.

Comment: I've done it and it works, super happy you helped, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) instead of `res.text()` to get the data as an object instead of a string.

Then you can use [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to update the page as usual.

Comment: I got into there, nice, now I am trying to get into how to use the DOM on Node, because is a runtime - and it says `ReferenceError: document is not defined` when I am trying to use the DOM

Comment: Oh. Missed that you are using Node.js. You'll want to use a template engine and not DOM then. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html if you are using Express (which you almost certainly should be)

Comment: Would this create any conflict if I am using ejs instead of pug?

Comment: If you've using EJS use EJS. Don't mix and match template engines.

Comment: I've done it and it works, glad you helped me and you spent time doing so, thank you so very much